# FOP – OutofMemoryError with multiple page sequence

Tags: java, apache-fop

I use Apache FOP 2.2 to generate PDF report. Whenever there are more than 20K records, I get “OutofMemoryError: Java heap space” error. I tried increasing the number of page-sequence which improved the performance but still gives the out of memory error when transforming XML to PDF for more than 20K records. Without multiple page-sequence, only 2K records were transformed successfully. Below are the XML structure and XSL template used.

Requirement is to generate PDF with at least 75K records (depends on the DB data). Please suggest how to modify XSL-FO template or XML format to fix this issue.

```html
<Report>
    <Header></Header>
    <Records>
        <IncompletedRecords>
            <IncompleteRec>
                <FName></FName>
                <LName></LName>
                <Address></Address>
                <LastUpdDate></LastUpdDate>
            </IncompleteRec>
            <IncompleteRec>
                <FName></FName>
                <LName></LName>
                <Address></Address>
                <LastUpdDate></LastUpdDate>
            </IncompleteRec>
            .
            .
            .
            <IncompleteRec>...</IncompleteRec>
            <IncompleteRec>...</IncompleteRec>
        </IncompletedRecords>
        <ApprovedRecords>
            <ApprovedRec>
                <FName></FName>
                <LName></LName>
                <Address></Address>
                <LastUpdDate></LastUpdDate>
            </ApprovedRec>
            <ApprovedRec>
                .
            </ApprovedRec>
            .
            .
            .
            <ApprovedRec>...</ApprovedRec>
            <ApprovedRec>...</ApprovedRec>
        </ApprovedRecords>
        <DeletedRecords>
            <DeletedRec>
                <FName></FName>
                <LName></LName>
                <Address></Address>
                <LastUpdDate></LastUpdDate>
            </DeletedRec>
            <DeletedRec>
                .
                .
            </DeletedRec>
            .
            .
            .
            <DeletedRec>...</DeletedRec>
            <DeletedRec>...</DeletedRec>
        </DeletedRecords>
        <PendingRecords>
            <PendingRec>
                <FName></FName>
                <LName></LName>
                <Address></Address>
                <LastUpdDate></LastUpdDate>
            </PendingRec>
            <PendingRec>
                .
                .
            </PendingRec>
            .
            .
            .
            <PendingRec>...</PendingRec>
            <PendingRec>...</PendingRec>
        </PendingRecords>
        <DeactivatedRecords>
            <DeactivatedRec>
                <FName></FName>
                <LName></LName>
                <Address></Address>
                <LastUpdDate></LastUpdDate>
            </DeactivatedRec>
            <DeactivatedRec>
                .
                .
            </DeactivatedRec>
            .
            .
            .
            <DeactivatedRec>...</DeactivatedRec>
            <DeactivatedRec>...</DeactivatedRec>
        </DeactivatedRecords>
        <RejectedRecords>
            <RejectedRec>
                <FName></FName>
                <LName></LName>
                <Address></Address>
                <LastUpdDate></LastUpdDate>
            </RejectedRec>
            <RejectedRec>
                .
            </RejectedRec>
            .
            .
            .
            <RejectedRec>...</RejectedRec>
            <RejectedRec>...</RejectedRec>
        </RejectedRecords>
    </Records>
</Report>
```

```
    <xsl:template match="Report">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page"
                page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-left="0.45in"
                margin-right="0.6in" margin-top="0.25in" margin-bottom="0.25in">
                <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" />
                <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <!-- 1st page sequence -->
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page"
            initial-page-number="1" id="myseq">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block text-align="end" font-size="10pt" font-family="serif"
                    line-height="14pt">
                    Page
                    <fo:page-number />
                    of
                    <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="myseq" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Header" />
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                            border-collapse="collapse">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2in" />
                            <fo:table-header border-bottom="1pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt"
                                    background-color="lightgrey" height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">First Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Address</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Changed By</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:call-template name="header.status">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Incomplete'" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                                <!-- No records -->
                                <xsl:if
                                    test="count(Records/IncompleteRecords/IncompleteRec) = 0">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="norecords">
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:apply-templates
                                    select="Records/IncompleteRecords/IncompleteRec"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

        <!-- 2nd page sequence -->
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page" id="myseq">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                            border-collapse="collapse">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2in" />
                            <fo:table-header border-bottom="1pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt"
                                    background-color="lightgrey" height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">First Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Address</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Changed By</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:call-template name="header.status">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Approved'" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                                <xsl:if test="count(Records/ApprovedRecords/ApprovedRec) = 0">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="norecords">
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:apply-templates
                                    select="Records/ApprovedRecords/ApprovedRec"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

        <!-- 3rd page sequence -->
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page" id="myseq">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                            border-collapse="collapse">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2in" />
                            <fo:table-header border-bottom="1pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt"
                                    background-color="lightgrey" height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">First Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Address</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Changed By</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:call-template name="header.status">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Deleted'" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                                <xsl:if test="count(Records/DeletedRecords/DeletedRec) = 0">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="norecords">
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:apply-templates
                                    select="Records/DeletedRecords/DeletedRec"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

        <!-- 4th page sequence -->
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page" id="myseq">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                            border-collapse="collapse">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2in" />
                            <fo:table-header border-bottom="1pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt"
                                    background-color="lightgrey" height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">First Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Address</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Changed By</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:call-template name="header.status">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Deactivated'" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                                <xsl:if test="count(Records/DeactivatedRecords/DeactivatedRec)=0">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="norecords">
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:apply-templates
                                    select="Records/DeactivatedRecords/DeactivatedRec"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

        <!-- 5th page sequence -->
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page" id="myseq">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                            border-collapse="collapse">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2in" />
                            <fo:table-header border-bottom="1pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt"
                                    background-color="lightgrey" height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">First Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Address</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Changed By</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:call-template name="header.status">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Pending Approval'" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                                <xsl:if test=" count(Records/PendingRecords/PendingRec) = 0">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="norecords">
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:apply-templates
                                    select="Records/PendingRecords/PendingRec"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

        <!-- 6th page sequence -->
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page" id="myseq">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                            border-collapse="collapse">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="1.5in" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2in" />
                            <fo:table-header border-bottom="1pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt"
                                    background-color="lightgrey" height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">First Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Name</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Address</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell background-color="lightgrey"
                                    height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                                    <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" margin-bottom="1mm"
                                        font-weight="bold">Last Changed By</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:call-template name="header.status">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Rejected'" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                                <xsl:if test="count(Records/RejectedRecords/RejectedRec) = 0">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="norecords">
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:apply-templates
                                    select="Records/RejectedRecords/RejectedRec"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- Report header -->
<!-- ========================= -->

<xsl:template match="Header">
    <fo:table width="100%" border-style="outset" border-width="0pt">
        <fo:table-column />
        <fo:table-column />
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell display-align="center" padding="0pt">
                    <fo:block>

                        <fo:external-graphic
                            src="url({resolve-uri('images', static-base-uri()) }/test_en.png)" />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell display-align="center" padding="0pt">
                    <fo:block text-align="right">
                        <fo:external-graphic
                            src="url({resolve-uri('images', static-base-uri()) }/test_en.png)" />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>

            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>

    <fo:block font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="2mm"
        color="darkblue" text-align="left">Report
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="2mm">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-size="8pt" space-after="5mm">
        <fo:float float="left">
            <fo:block font-size="8pt" space-after="5mm">
                <xsl:value-of select="PublicationName" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:float>
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right" space-after="5mm">
            <xsl:value-of
                select="concat(
         format-dateTime(CreateReportDate, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ()),' ',
         format-dateTime(CreateReportDate, '[h]:[m01]:[s01] [PN,2-2]', 'en', (), ()) )" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block>

    <fo:block text-align="center">
        <fo:inline-container>
            <fo:table margin-top="2mm">
                <fo:table-column column-width="3.25in" />
                <fo:table-column column-width="2in" />
                <fo:table-column column-width="2.25in" />

                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row background-color="lightblue">
                        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" height="0.25in"
                            display-align="center">
                            <fo:block text-align="left" background-color="lightblue"
                                color="darkblue" font-size="6pt">
                                Status:
                                <fo:inline color="black">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Status" />
                                </fo:inline>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell height="0.25in" display-align="center">
                            <fo:block font-size="6pt" background-color="lightblue"
                                color="darkblue" text-align="right">
                                Created Date:
                                <fo:inline color="black">
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="concat(
              format-date(CreatedDateFrom, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ()), ' - ',
              format-date(CreatedDateTo, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())
              )" />
                                </fo:inline>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-right="3pt" height="0.25in"
                            display-align="center">
                            <fo:block font-size="6pt" background-color="lightblue"
                                color="darkblue" text-align="right">
                                Last Edited Date:
                                <fo:inline color="black">
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="concat(
             format-date(LastEditedDateFrom, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ()), ' - ',
              format-date(LastEditedDateTo, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())
             )" />
                                </fo:inline>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:inline-container>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- child element: Record -->
<!-- ========================= -->

<xsl:template
    match="Records/IncompleteRecords/IncompleteRec">

    <!-- Display records if any -->
    <fo:table-row border-bottom="0.5pt solid black">
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-before="3pt"
            padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="First Name" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Name" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Changed By" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="format-date(ChangeDate, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastChangedBy" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- child element: Record -->
<!-- ========================= -->
<xsl:template
    match="Records/ApprovedRecords/ApprovedRec">
    <fo:table-row border-bottom="0.5pt solid black">
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-before="3pt"
            padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="First Name" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Name" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Changed By" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="format-date(ChangeDate, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastChangedBy" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- child element: Record -->
<!-- ========================= -->
<xsl:template match="Records/DeletedRecords/DeletedRec">
    <fo:table-row border-bottom="0.5pt solid black">
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-before="3pt"
            padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="First Name" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Name" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Changed By" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="format-date(ChangeDate, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastChangedBy" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- child element: Record -->
<!-- ========================= -->
<xsl:template
    match="Records/DeactivatedRecords/DeactivatedRec">
    <fo:table-row border-bottom="0.5pt solid black">
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-before="3pt"
            padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="First Name" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Name" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Changed By" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="format-date(ChangeDate, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastChangedBy" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- child element: Record -->
<!-- ========================= -->
<xsl:template
    match="Records/PendingRecords/PendingRec">
    <fo:table-row border-bottom="0.5pt solid black">
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-before="3pt"
            padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="First Name" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Name" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Changed By" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="format-date(ChangeDate, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastChangedBy" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- child element: Record -->
<!-- ========================= -->
<xsl:template
    match="Records/RejectedRecords/RejectedRec">
    <fo:table-row border-bottom="0.5pt solid black">
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" padding-before="3pt"
            padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="First Name" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Name" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Last Changed By" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="format-date(ChangeDate, '[MNn,*-3] [D], [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastChangedBy" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- Display Table header -->
<!-- ========================= -->

<xsl:template name="header.status">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="3pt" background-color="lightgrey"
            height="0.25in" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4">
            <fo:block background-color="lightgrey" font-weight="bold">
                Status:
                <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ========================= -->
<!-- Display No records -->
<!-- ========================= -->
<xsl:template name="norecords">
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell height="0.25in" display-align="center"
            number-columns-spanned="4">
            <fo:block margin-bottom="1mm" text-align="center">
                No records found
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl: stylesheet>
```

Comment: What heap size do you have?

Comment: Heap size is 1 GB

Answer (score 0):

If every table row is the same height, such that every page has the same number of rows, then you can fake the breaking of the table over multiple pages by making multiple tables that each have the rows for one page.

Comment: Row height depends on “Address” field in the XML. It’s not a mandatory field. It can occupy up to 3 lines in a row if it has data or just a line if there is no data. So, the total number of rows in each page will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, I think you just have to keep increasing the RAM of the server until you get to a limit you can't go beyond. I have used 70gig ram to generate some extremely big pdf before.